# Why nodejs doesn't set xhr to be true?

Tags: node.js

I have nodejs with express application:

```
const app: express.Application = express();
```

And I create a api router:

```
const api = express.Router();
const auth = express.Router();
auth.post('/login', (...) => { ... });
api.use('/auth', auth);
app.use('/api', cors(), api);
```

In the `/api/auth/login` I get the `req` object with `xhr` property set to `false`.

Why? I do this request using `axios` with `post` method so is it `xhr` request. why nodejs not set `xhr` property to true? what can be the problem?

Comment: `req.xhr` is set to true / false depending on the client's call: `A Boolean property that is true if the request’s X-Requested-With header field is “XMLHttpRequest”, indicating that the request was issued by a client library such as jQuery.`

Comment: What I need to do? I try to do the request in postman and I get the same result. Do I need to defined something in nodejs application?

Comment: I don't get why you need it to be an xhr request. Documentation says xhr will be set to true basically only when request is made with ajax.

Comment: Because I want to send an error if the request is xhr I send the error as json, if not I send as raw html

Comment: in this case, you should check `req.accepts` to establish what format should be used: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.accepts